# Wordpress deleting subdomain from the URL

Tags: subdomains

Finally I've solved the wildcard subdomain for my hosting. But now I'm facing another problem.

If you try https://randomname.minepi.hu then it will redirect for the main domain and wordpress deleting the given data. If you try this link: https://randonname.minepi.hu/test/ you can see its a simple php page and now the subdomain stays there, and I can processs the given info on the site.

Okay the SSL have to be setup somehow later, not sure how could I do that since I'm just using Easy SSL now, and I don't see wildcard subdomain options but thats a different tale. Right now I would be happy if Wordpress not deleting the subdomain from the URL.

Maybe its some edit needed in the MySQL tables, or are there any easier options?

Answer (score 0):

Okay I found the answer. I had to add this to wp-config.php:

```
define('WP_SITEURL', 'https://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);
define('WP_HOME', 'https://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you use Multisite mode for WP?
If not, the mechanism for enabling Multisite mode is shown below:
Edit wp-config.php and enable the option :

```
define( 'WP_ALLOW_MULTISITE', true );
```

Next, in the control panel, find the network Setup tab in the Tools section. Select the address format for the network.
Update your files wp-config.php:

```
define('MULTISITE', true);
define('SUBDOMAIN_INSTALL', false);
define('DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE', 'new-multisite-setup.dev');
define('PATH_CURRENT_SITE', '/');
define('SITE_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1);
define('BLOG_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1);
```

and .htaccess :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$ $1wp-admin/ [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(.*\.php)$ $2 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

In your control panel you will find a new option in the admin navigation menu called Sites. Go to the Sites tab and add your subdomain by filling in all the fields. After that, the problem with the transition should stop.

Comment: Nope I don't need multisite at all :) 

I'm just using a custom php script, what get data from $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];

You can check out. https://ktscript.minepi.hu/pi-network-app-telepites/

At the middle of the page before article 4. If you delete your name and use the minepi.hu it will load you an invite code random generator if you use the link with your affiliate it will write your name.

I'm wondering why the same script not working on the main page.There is only the generator showing all the time.

Comment: It probably doesn't see the subdomain and outputs the main domain. Try to handle the transition to a particular address yourself via      add_filter('request', function( $vars ) {... $request = urldecode($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']); ... });

Comment: It's interesting I haven't change any code and now working the same script on the main site, but the SSL is a big problem.

I have no idea how to setup SSL what support wildcards, and right now no image is loaded if the user try this feature, plus the warning message about the insecure site. Too bad that I can't find any tutorial on this for wordpress, only for the big hosting sites and we using a local one.